# How to displays commas in integers in CSV macro in confluence wiki

Tags: csv, macros, escaping, number-formatting, confluence

I'm using the CSV macro in Confluence 4.x and one of my columns has integer data. When displayed with the macro, the wiki isn't putting commas into the large integers (I have 7 digit integers in my CSV file). I set the column type to "I" for integer, but this didn't help. Is this a limitation of the macro or a setting that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the following options:

- Change delimiter to space and insert commas manually
- [upgrade to 5.1](https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/display/TBL/CSV+Macro#CSVmacro-Commonparameters) to use columnType `FC` or `CC`